# cocos2d scenes vs layers

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

im creating a game that doesn't use a traditional menu system - where you have different scenes (like settings, about, new game, etc.) and then you just change the scene according to a button press or something like that - but the menu is built into the actual game (buttons are placed on the game layer).
When a button is pressed different layers appear (which can fill the whole screen) based on the game logic. The idea is to have the game layer always present (so the game state never changes and the game layer doesn't need to re initialize even if you change some parameters). Layers more or less contain buttons and a list of different sprites which u can scroll through.

My biggest concern is that the performance/memory would drop due to to many images on screen (the game layer can contain up to 100 sprites and is always present - if there is a layer in front of the game layer the game layer gets paused and hidden).

Game scene setup:

- game layer
- menu layer
- dynamic layer (layer that is added when some button is pressed)

If i would change the dynamic layers into a scene would it be any different? (instead of creating a new layer i would just create a new scene and push it on the scene stack without killing the game layer). Are these 2 approaches the same or are there any key differences (memory/performance wise)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use pushScene/popScene in this case. It saves you a lot of trouble, for example the background scene will automatically be paused.

Memory consumption should be about the same. Almost all of the memory used by a game is texture memory and audio buffers, so don't concern yourself with how many sprites you may have in memory but rather how many different textures they'll be using.

Comment: the dynamic layer displays about a 100 different textures/images + the textures that are in the game layer (let say 20) - it's just like if you would have a image picker inside a game which would list all the images that are on your device. Thats why i'm asking which one to use. Using scenes does give the advantage of pausing the game and such but can you manipulate the paused scene from the active one (call its function)?

Answer (score 0):

no, you should use one layer for a scene.
and use ccsprite instead sub layer.
If you put all of your scene into shareDirector. it will be slowly and possiable crash.

Comment: there are max 2 scenes in the stack - the one with the game and on top of that a dynamic scene.